# Investigation On

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about the mysterious usage of the preposition "*on*" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/1998/06/22/business/time-orders-investigation-on-accuracy-of-cnn-report.html):

> Time Orders ***Investigation On*** Accuracy Of CNN Report

Would "*investigation* ***of***" be better than "*investigation* ***on***"?  Could it be that the author used "*on*" because he wanted to avoid the usage of two "*of*"s in succession?

Comment: Congratulations on having a feeling for what sounds good and bad in English! As Jason Patterson's [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57576/6700) explains, the author almost certainly made the unusual choice of "on" in order to avoid two "of"s in succession, which would sound somewhat bad here.

Answer (score 6):

Typically *investigation* is followed by *of* or less commonly *into*.  *On* is used even less often, though I have seen it before.  I think that the headline would read more naturally with "Investigation **Of** Accuracy *Of* CNN" or better, to avoid the double "of", as you suggest, "Investigation **Into** Accuracy *Of* CNN."

A [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=investigation%20on%2Cinvestigation%20of%2Cinvestigation%20into&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cinvestigation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binvestigation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInvestigation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinvestigation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binvestigation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInvestigation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BINVESTIGATION%20OF%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinvestigation%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binvestigation%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInvestigation%20into%3B%2Cc0) of the three phrases shows "of" being used roughly ten times more than "into," which is used roughly five times more than "on."

As with any words or phrases, these three phrases aren't exactly identical, but I can't find any hard and fast rule for their usage.  The only one that I was able to think of is that when criminal investigations are being discussed, "investigation into" is typically used.

> The police have started an investigation into the murder of John Smith.

Answer (score 3):

In American English, "investigation on" usually occurs in the context of exposé TV journalism (e.g. *60 Minutes* and *20/20*), where the word "investigation" is used more or less as a synonym for "investigative piece" or "exposé" -- hence the "on".

The journalists complete an investigation *of* something, and then urge the audience to stay tuned for the upcoming investigation (i.e. the segment based on their sleuthing) *on* something.

For example: http://www.kwch.com/news/local-news/homeowners-respond-to-60-minutes-investigation-on-flooring/31577558

Comment: Interesting observation! And it sounds right to me (native AmE) even though I've hardly watched any TV in the last 15 years.